# iOS 11.4.1 shows device Jailbroken when it is not

Tags: jailbreak, ios11.4

I have been using different techniques for jailbreak detection and it was working fine till iOS 11.4. However when I upgraded my iOS to latest 11.4.1 it is showing me the device is jailbroken when the device is not. This issue we are facing only in iOS 11.4.1 and iOS 12 Beta.
Following were the techniques we are using:

1.Process forking

2."CydiaApp" Scheme Detection

3.Check for suspicious/root folders and files

4.Check for folders that was created during the jailbreak process

5.Check for write permission for non user folder

Is there any thing related to these files and folder access permission we are doing wrong to detect the jailbreak detection?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You neglect to say _which_ of these triggered. But if you're testing for anything in `/var`, those files will persist across updates.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible always and in all iOS11.4.1. Because of this I am unable to find the root cause or, which of the detection fails actually.

Comment: You provide a list of things you check. So why exactly can't you check them one by one and see which one is faulty?

Answer (score 1):

But which one is actually gives you false positive?

If I were to guess, I would say that checking write permissions is not reliable. The way that iOS protects unauthorized access to system files is not with permissions but mainly with sandbox profiles. With that in place Apple can assign any permissions they want to system files, sandboxing will still protect the system. Even when you jailbreak your phone you still have sandboxing in place (don't remember any jailbreak that would disable sandboxing completely) and often limited by it when, for example, injecting your CydiaSubstrate dylibs into system daemons/applications that operate under sandbox profiles. That's the whole security of iOS - code signing, entitlements, sandboxing, IPC. No need for POSIX permissions which Apple actually doesn't use that much.

Checking for suspicions directories and files could also give you false positives and is not very reliable in general. Apple often changes it's root file system, you never know what might be in the new iOS version. Of course, if it's related to Cydia then it should be ok.

And that's, in part, why Apple doesn't like AppStore apps checking for jailbreak and often rejects them because of it. Not only you try to access something you shouldn't, which makes it hard to distinguish between jailbreak detection and actual usage of private API to circumvent iOS security. But given that jailbreak is all about very specific kernel patches and things that you wouldn't have access inside AppStore app due to sandboxing anyway (launching unsigned binaries, modifying root partition), there's no reliable way of detecting jailbreak in general. Forking, Cydia, support for CydiaSubstrate - all of that is optional and depends on specific jailbreak implementation. With recent jalbreaks that's even more relevant - all of them are very different and not completely finished lacking some features that were standard in the past. Even more importantly, if Apple decides to change something in iOS, in might trigger jailbreak detecting code by accident. False positive is much worse than false negative.

In the end, no matter what you do, every jailbreak detection code can be easily patched or hooked. When you're in control of the system, apps are no longer able to protect themselves. That's all offtopic but it's a good reason to just ignore jailbreak.

Comment: Thank You @creker for your response. I am unable to find the API which gives the false positive as issue is not 100% reproducible and frequency of the issue observation is less than 10%. Can you suggest how I can proceed with this to check which actually gives false Positive.

Comment: Why not just log every check? Give it multiple runs until it triggers and read the log.